# matplotlib mathtext slanted fractions

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

Is it possible with matplotlib to create a  [slanted fractions](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics#Fractions_and_Binomials) ( /sfrac{1}{1} in Latex)

I tried `r'$/sfrac{1}{2}$'`, but I get nothing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use real LaTeX as follows:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Use LaTeX for rendering
matplotlib.rcParams["text.usetex"] = True
# load the xfrac package
matplotlib.rcParams["text.latex.preamble"].append(r'\usepackage{xfrac}')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot([0,1],[1,0])
ax.text(.5, .5, r'$\sfrac{1}{2}$')
```

This creates:

[image]

You need to have a working LaTeX in your system plus of course the LaTeX xfrac package.

Comment: Is there any other way rather installing anything?